# Cell location update notification when screen is off

Tags: android, location, cellid

I'm writing software which requires cell location updates to be received or checked constantly. The problem I'm having is that when the screen is off: a) notifications stop (using PhonestateListener); b) when a timer is used to check the cell info of the current cell, old cell info is returned.

I've spent a lot of time searching the reason for this and found a couple of posts on this subject. However I never found an answer or a workaround to the problem, accept for having the phone turn the screen on constantly to get a new cell location.

I've check the android RIL source code and it seems as soon as the screen is turned off, a broadcast receiver in the RIL sets the screen state to off and stops URC messages from the modem. I decided to try and call these internal functions to, say, reset the screen state (bad solution!), but I kept getting permission errors due to system intents being created as a result of my actions (I even tried by getting su permission).

Finally, I tried to communicate directly with the modem to send a +CSQ command (using 'invokeOemRilRequestStrings' function in the RIL). However, that part failed as I kept getting errors about object type not being same as expected class type...

So... I would like to know if anyone can point me to a solution to get this thing done. Or is it an impossible thing to do on android without modifying the ROM?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try registering for location updates in a separate Android service having FOREGROUND priority?